# File preview is not visible and file links do not work in laravel file manage

Tags: laravel, unisharp-file-manager

Laravel filemanager works fine on localhost, but not on the server
When I go to the link to the file,

[image]

I get the following error :

```
You don't have permission to access /public/storage/picture/picture2.jpg on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Checked everything but couldn't fix it.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming because the application is not able to access the file. Check the file permissions for folder "/public/storage/picture/" make sure it has the correct permissions and all the objects inside this folder too. Then the files should be visible.

Comment: I did permissions 755 but still didn't work